# Who fired rockets at Malaysian MH17 flight?

Tags: aviation, mh17

This is still pretty confusing who actually shot down the MH17 flight ? Many news websites claim that the Plane was shot down by Russian-backed Rebels,

> There is overwhelming, but largely circumstantial evidence that Russian-backed rebels mistakenly brought down the Boeing 777, killing
>   all 298 people on board, having mistaken it for a Ukrainian military
>   aircraft.

Source: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/ukraine/10993470/Putin-facing-multi-million-pound-legal-action-over-alleged-role-in-MH17-crash.html

While other claims that it was indeed shot down by Ukrainian troops,

> A source within the Ukrainian defense department claims that Malaysia Airlines Flight 17 was accidentally shot down by Ukrainian
>   troops during a military exercise near Donetsk which took place on
>   July 17.

Source: http://www.globalresearch.ca/kiev-source-ukraine-accidentally-shot-down-mh17-during-exercises/5393441

What really happened does any one has a clue ?

Comment: Not exactly a dupe, but they are both basically asking "what happened to mh17?"